# Finding the smallest difference between a sorted-set of floats

Tags: clojure, sortedset

If I've got a sorted-set of floats, how can I find the smallest difference between any 2 values in that sorted set?

For example, if the sorted set contains

```
#{1.0 1.1 1.3 1.45 1.7 1.71}
```

then the result I'm after would be 0.01, as the difference between 1.71 and 1.7 is the smallest difference between any 2 values in that sorted set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

As Alan pointed out to me, the problem stated this was a sorted set, so we could do this much simpler:

```
(def s (sorted-set 1.0 1.1 1.3 1.45 1.7 1.71))
(reduce min (map - (rest s) s)))
=> 0.01
```

---

**Original Answer**

Assuming the set is unordered, although ordering it might be better.

Given

```
(def s #{1.0 1.1 1.3 1.45 1.7 1.71})
```

We could get relevant pairs, as in, for every number in the list, pair it with all the numbers to the right of it:

```
(def pairs 
   (loop [r [] s (into [] s)]
      (if-let [[f & v] s]
         (recur (concat r (for [i v] [f i]))
                v)
         r)))
=> ([1.0 1.45] [1.0 1.7] [1.0 1.3] [1.0 1.1] [1.0 1.71] [1.45 1.7] [1.45 1.3] 
    [1.45 1.1] [1.45 1.71] [1.7 1.3] [1.7 1.1] [1.7 1.71] [1.3 1.1] [1.3 1.71] 
    [1.1 1.71])
```

Now, we will want to look at the absolute values of the differences between every pair:

```
(defn abs [x] (Math/abs x))
```

Put it all together, and get the minimum value:

```
(reduce min (map (comp abs (partial apply -)) pairs))
```

Which will give us the desired output, `0.01`

---

That last line could be more explicitly written as

```
(reduce min
    (map (fn[[a b]]
           (abs (- a b)))
         pairs))
```

Comment: `(apply min (map - (rest s) s))`

Answer (score -2):

I think using the Clojure built-in function `partition` is the simplest way:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def vals [1.0 1.1 1.3 1.45 1.7 1.71])
(spyx vals)

(def pairs (partition 2 1 vals))
(spyx pairs)

(def deltas (mapv #(apply - (reverse %)) pairs))
(spyx deltas)

(println "result=" (apply 

vals => [1.0 1.1 1.3 1.45 1.7 1.71]
pairs => ((1.0 1.1) (1.1 1.3) (1.3 1.45) (1.45 1.7) (1.7 1.71))
deltas => [0.10000000000000009 0.19999999999999996 0.1499999999999999 0.25 0.010000000000000009]
result= 0.010000000000000009
```

Comment: Not really, this assumes the minimum is at consecutive numbers. This fails for `[1.0 1.1 1.3 1.7 1.45 1.71])` - Moved 1.7 back a little.

Comment: The problem stated it was a "sorted set of floats".  If the original set were unsorted, it would still be better to sort it first (n*log n) and compare neighbors than to compare every pair (n^2).

Comment: Right, missed the sorted part. In that case, `partition` might even be too much, one could simply do `(map - s (rest s))`. Ill update my answer as well :)